# Check if the key in redux store is connected to any component in DOM right now

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a redux store with a reducer data and using redux observable to fill this data in store. I am trying to load some data in store when component is mounted and remove that data when component is unmounted. But before removing I want to check that this data is not used by any other mounted component. What I have till now is this

Store:

```
{
   data: {}
}
```

My component needs itemList, I dispatch an action LOAD_ITEMS, one epic loads itemList and puts it in store

```
{
    data: { items: {someItems}}
}
```

This component has following connection to store -

```
componentDidMount () {
   if (!data.items) {
      dipatch(LOAD_ITEMS)
   }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   // Before doing this I want to make sure that these items are not 
  // used by any other mounted componeted.
   dispatch(REMOVE_ITEMS_FROM_STORE);
}
mapStateToProps = () => ({
    data: store.data
})
```

One way I tried was to save count of all mounted components which uses items from store in store with a key activeComponents. Like following

```
{
   data: {
       items: {someItems}
       activeComponents: 2 // count of mounted components which are 
                           //using items from store
   }
}
```

So if there are two components which needs items from store the count of activeComponents will be 2, so items will be removed from store only if this count is one, on other removal attempts just activeComponents count is reduced by 1

But this is very complicated approach, I suppose there must be some better and proper way do this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea with storing the number of activeComponents is kinda the right approach, but you should use a boolean value, that will make it much more simple to handle.

So basically instead of storing `activeComponents: 3`, you can just do `isUsed: true / false`